# MySQL and lots of queries

Tags: java, mysql, caching, web, bigdata

I have a Java application, which is kind of a web scraper. It parses lots of, lets call it - rows. The point is, when scraping a web, check, if a row found on a certain page is new, or is it old (I do a query to MySQL database at this point to check if it exists in it). If it is new, I put it to a seperate array and do another query to add that line to database, so when doing a next scraping, that row could be recognized as old. The problem is, that web page has about 90 thousand of these rows, and performance is quite slow. Sometimes MySQL server even crashes.

I would like you hear your opinion, which of these options should I choose(or maybe something else):

1. Choose other DBMS, like MongoDB or some other?
2. Do not put rows to database, but use some caching solution? (what solution, then?)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you show us your code? Might be able to give you a better answer that way

Answer (score 0):

You may use Apache Cassandra instead of mysql. It is fast at write and you'll not need a cache. You can avoid the read before write, if at application level define a proper unique key, using a hash function, such that if you apply the hash on same old page and new page it will result same unique key. You always insert you don't have to read.

You may do also a conditional insert too, but this will slow down the write throughput because it has to do a paxos consensus on all replicas.

Answer (score 0):

Mantain in memory two lists:

- Already visited pages
- To be visited pages

Now the algorythm is something like:

1. Read a to be visited page
2. Extract links from that page and for every link
3. If link is present in already visited pages discard it
4. If link is present in to be visited pages discard it
5. If not present in already visited pages and in to be visited pages access the database and search it. If present discard it. If not present add it as to be visited page both in the database and in the in memory list.
6. Remove the current page from to be visited pages and add it to the already visited pages

In this solution you will access the databases very rarely. Consider to limit the size of the two lists to a reasonable dimension to solve problems of memory errors.